# Сервер отвергает мой запрос

Tags: java, telegram, apache-modules, socks5, http-status-code-400

Добрый день, столкнулся с такой проблемой.
При запросе на сервер `https://api.telegram.org` он отвечает мне
`400 The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port`

Вот код программы:

```
public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception {       
    Registry<ConnectionSocketFactory> reg = RegistryBuilder.<ConnectionSocketFactory>create()
            .register("http", new MyConnectionSocketFactory())
            .register("https", new MySSLConnectionSocketFactory(
                    SSLContexts.createSystemDefault(),
                    new String[] { "TLSv1", "SSLv3" }, null,
                    SSLConnectionSocketFactory.getDefaultHostnameVerifier()))
            .build();

    PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager cm = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager(reg);

    CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom()
            .setSSLHostnameVerifier(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.getDefaultHostnameVerifier())
            .setConnectionManager(cm)
            .build();

    try {
        InetSocketAddress socksaddr = new InetSocketAddress("mysockeyaddres", 8080);
        HttpClientContext context = HttpClientContext.create();
        context.setAttribute("socks.address", socksaddr);


        HttpHost target = new HttpHost("api.telegram.org", 443, "https");
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet("/");


        System.out.println("Executing request " + request + " to " + target + " via SOCKS proxy " + socksaddr);
        System.out.println(request.toString());

        CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(target, request, context);

        String responseString = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(), "UTF-8");
        try {
            System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
            System.out.println(response.toString());
            System.out.println(responseString);
            EntityUtils.consume(response.getEntity());
        } finally {
            response.close();
        }
    } finally {
        httpclient.close();
    }
}

static class MyConnectionSocketFactory implements ConnectionSocketFactory {

    public Socket createSocket(final HttpContext context) throws IOException {
        InetSocketAddress socksaddr = (InetSocketAddress) context.getAttribute("socks.address");
        Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.SOCKS, socksaddr);
        return new Socket(proxy);
    }

    public Socket connectSocket(
            final int connectTimeout,
            final Socket socket,
            final HttpHost host,
            final InetSocketAddress remoteAddress,
            final InetSocketAddress localAddress,
            final HttpContext context) throws IOException, ConnectTimeoutException {
        Socket sock;
        if (socket != null) {
            sock = socket;
        } else {
            sock = createSocket(context);
        }
        if (localAddress != null) {
            sock.bind(localAddress);
        }
        try {
            sock.connect(remoteAddress, connectTimeout);
        } catch (SocketTimeoutException ex) {
            throw new ConnectTimeoutException(ex, host, remoteAddress.getAddress());
        }
        return sock;
    }

}

static class MySSLConnectionSocketFactory extends SSLConnectionSocketFactory {

    public MySSLConnectionSocketFactory(final SSLContext sslContext) {
        super(sslContext);
    }

    public MySSLConnectionSocketFactory(SSLContext createDefault, HostnameVerifier defaultHostnameVerifier) {
        super(createDefault, defaultHostnameVerifier);
    }

    public MySSLConnectionSocketFactory(SSLContext sslContext, String[] supportedProtocols, String[] supportedCipherSuites, HostnameVerifier hostnameVerifier) {
        super(sslContext, supportedProtocols, supportedCipherSuites, hostnameVerifier);

    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(final HttpContext context) throws IOException {
        InetSocketAddress socksaddr = (InetSocketAddress) context.getAttribute("socks.address");
        Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.SOCKS, socksaddr);

        return new Socket(proxy);
    }

    public Socket connectSocket(
            final int connectTimeout,
            final Socket socket,
            final HttpHost host,
            final InetSocketAddress remoteAddress,
            final InetSocketAddress localAddress,
            final HttpContext context) throws IOException, ConnectTimeoutException {
        Socket sock;
        if (socket != null) {
            sock = socket;
        } else {
            sock = createSocket(context);
        }
        if (localAddress != null) {
            sock.bind(localAddress);
        }
        try {
            sock.connect(remoteAddress, connectTimeout);
        } catch (SocketTimeoutException ex) {
            throw new ConnectTimeoutException(ex, host, remoteAddress.getAddress());
        }
        return sock;
    }
 }
}
```

Запрос делаю используя `Apache httpclient-4.5.5` и сокеты пятой версии.

Update:
    Вопрос закрыт, спасибо @zRrr , за, по сути, ответ на мой вопрос.
    Для решения проблемы необходимо создать новый экземпляр класса [SSLConnectionSocketFactory](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient/4.5/org/apache/http/conn/ssl/SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java#SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket%28java.net.Socket%2Cjava.lang.String%2Cint%2Corg.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext%29), но изменить несколько методов с private на protected, чтобы переопределить метод connectSocket

Comment: кмк, вы зря переопределили `connectSocket`, в оригинальном классе там [есть немного ssl-магии](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient/4.5/org/apache/http/conn/ssl/SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java#317)

Comment: @zRrr, я тоже подозреваю об этом, но если не переопределить его, то запрос, почему-то, строится без носков.

Comment: @zRrr, проверю магию, спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Почитайте новости о **Роскомнадзоре** и **Telegram**:

> Напомним, Роскомнадзор блокирует мессенджер Telegram с 16 апреля, исполняя решение Таганского суда Москвы. Решение суда стало следствием того, что владелец Telegram Павел Дуров отказался передать ФСБ России ключи шифрования переписки пользователей, как того требует российское законодательство, в частности, для эффективной борьбы с терроризмом.

Comment: Я прекрасно об этом знаю, поэтому запросы я делаю через SOCKS5 прокси.

Comment: Проверьте работоспособность прокси

Comment: Я, может быть, что-то не так понимаю, но разве у меня нет возможности просто зашифровать свой запрос и отправить его через любое кол-во проки к серверу?